# Scala Merge output lists into single list

Tags: list, scala, merge, concatenation

I have two lists

```
val list1 = List("customer1", "customer2")
list1: List[String] = List(customer1, customer2)

val list2 = List("John||32||Phone","Michael||34||Laptop")
list2: List[String] = List(John||32||Phone, Michael||34||Laptop)
```

I'm trying to get output as below list

```
List((customer1,John),(customer1,32),(customer1,Phone),(customer2,Michael),(customer2,34),(customer2,Laptop))
```

Below is my code

```
val finalList = list1 zip list2
finalList: List[(String, String)] = List((customer1,John||32||Phone), (customer2,Michael||34||Laptop))

finalList.foreach{
        case (fieldName,fieldDetail) => {
          val cusList = fieldName + "-" + fieldDetail.replace("||",",")
          val cusDetailList = cusList.split("-") match {
            case Array(k, v) =>
              v.split(",").map(value => (k, value)).toList
          }
          println(cusDetailList)
        }
}
```

It prints as

```
List((customer1,John), (customer1,32), (customer1,Phone))
List((customer2,Michael), (customer2,34), (customer2,Laptop))
```

I'm unable to get the output list as below

```
List((customer1,John),(customer1,32),(customer1,Phone),(customer2,Michael),(customer2,34),(customer2,Laptop))
```

Comment: Maybe you want `flatMap` instead of `foreach` and return the list instead of printing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to flatten the result list. This does the trick:

```
val list = list1 zip list2 flatMap {
  case (s1, s2) => s2.split("\\|\\|").map((s1, _))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`flatten`](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-flatten-list-lists-in-scala-with-flatten-method/):

```
scala> val lol = List(List(1,2), List(3,4))
lol: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2), List(3, 4))
scala> val result = lol.flatten
result: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Or [`flatMap`](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/collection-scala-flatmap-examples-map-flatten/).